# database table design for ratings in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

i am designing ratings table in mysql. The thing is the following:

> a) The one that gives rating to other can be different type
>   (Admin,Client, Provider or anything else in the future)
>
> b) The one that receives rating from other can be different
>   type(Admin,Client,Provider or anything else in the future)
>
> c) Giving ratings to others happen on when There's an order(imagine
>   just you go to website and order food. when they get you food, you
>   rate them) . but orders could be different kind. In my case order
>   means Freight Delivery. So I can have RoadOrder, SeaOrder.

After looking at the above things, I came to conclusion to have tables like this:

**1)  all_ratings table
(This table doesn't calculate the current ratings for each kind of user. There are 3 morphs here)**

```
id | from_userable_type | from_userable_id | to_userable_type | to_userable_id | orderable_type | orderable_id | rating
```

[image]

**2) ratings table(which calculates current rating. all_ratings just saves
 any kind of rating from each user, whereas ratings table has the final
 rating. ratingable_id and ratingable_type could be any type of user)**

```
id | quantity  | current_rating |  ratingable_id | ratingable_type
```

[image]

Users table

```
id | name | email | userable_id | userable_type
```

Admins,Clients,Providers(they look the same for now)

```
id
```

RoadOrder table

```
id | from_place  | to_place | ...etc
```

The question: What do you think? is this the right table schema for this type of scenario?

Comment: 1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSVCc.png  2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN6Zm.png

Comment: I updated it. take a look.

Comment: Why isn't the type of the user stored in the user table?

Comment: there's an users table and it's connected to admins table, clients table, serviceproviders table with polymorphic relationships.

Comment: So, you don't need to repeat that relation in the table `all_ratings`, since this is an information you can retrieve from the user table that is already in relation. I would like to see the tables structure of : users, usertype, order and ordertype please

Comment: users (id, name, userable_id, userable_type )Admins(id). Clients(id). Providers(id). userable_type will be the model itself , sometimes admins, clients or providers.

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55256647/edit) please, this is barely readable in comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190355/discussion-between-nika-khurashvili-and-cid).